# Getting OpenGL error but not using OpenGL

Tags: android

I'm getting the following error in my Logcat:

```
E/Adreno200-ES20﹕ <qgl2DrvAPI_glClear:55>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x506
```

I'm using a Motorola XT925 running Android 4.0.4 (api15). I am not directly using OpenGl and assuming behind the curtain, it is.

In trying to keep memory consumption down, I have a fragment that cleans up the memory it uses, clear caches and images returning to the previous parent activity.  The issue I have is once this error occurs my application stops drawing, so the view I see is wrong. I'm not sure if this is a case of issues with the phone itself or something else.

Is there any suggestions on how to debug this one? Since I'm not using OpenGL directly I'm not sure where to start on fixing this on my app.

Thanks.

Comment: debugging 101 comment things until you can't reproduce the bug and narrow it down to something concrete. Without knowing exactly what you're doing, you'll hardly find any help here.

Answer (score 0):

Try another device or an emulator -- looks like it's just a bug in the Adreno driver.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to close the hardware acceleration.

```
Class<View> c = View.class;
Method setLayerTypeMethod = 
c.getDeclaredMethod("setLayerType",int.class, Paint.class);
setLayerTypeMethod.invoke(this, View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```